# Get back a running terminal in sublime-text's terminus

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am using the [Sublime text terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) extension.
If I open the terminal in the panel and run a job (Say a python script) and while the script is running if I do ctrl+f to open the find and replace panel, the open terminal disappears because sublime supports only 1 panel.

But if I open the terminal in panel again, it opens a new terminal, and not the same one where the job was running and I am unable to get the job results.

If I set up localhost in the terminus terminal and remove it using ctrl+f, the localhost is kept running which indicates that sublime doesn't terminate the job while closing the terminal.

Is there a way to get the same terminal back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of available panels is available via the Panel Chooser; it displays all panels available, which includes those built in and those added by packages:

[image: Panel Chooser]

If you're on ST3, left click it to open the menu; on ST~~4~~ right click to get the menu.

Note also that the [Terminus README](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) includes information related to toggling panels, such as this default key binding that toggles the panel open and closed and will create it if it's not present:

```json
    { 
        "keys": ["alt+`"], "command": "toggle_terminus_panel"
    }
```

There are also example key bindings for having more than one Terminus panel at a time demonstrated in this [tips video for Terminus](https://youtu.be/FQsxc63Y5HQ) (I am the author of the video); the panel chooser is also demonstrated there.

Comment: This makes sense. Great video.
BTW, when I manually do ctrl+w on the terminus panel, it terminates the jobs and closes the panel. Is there a way to make it give a warning if a job is running?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no; once something is running, key presses either get sent to the running program or Sublime interprets them as bindings. Terminus is open ended enough to run anything you want, so it can't tell if you're running a program that is itself also running a program. Best case there is to disable that key and then manually `exit` or such